# Items in ListBox don't stretch properly

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox, listboxitem, stretch

Check this xaml:

```
<Window
  x:Class="MainWindow"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
  Width="300">
  <ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
      Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
    <ListBox.ItemsSource>
      <x:Array Type="{x:Type sys:Int32}">
        <sys:Int32>25</sys:Int32>
        <sys:Int32>10</sys:Int32>
        <sys:Int32>50</sys:Int32>
        <sys:Int32>30</sys:Int32>
        <sys:Int32>80</sys:Int32>
      </x:Array>
    </ListBox.ItemsSource>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
      </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Background="#FFE41515">
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="name" Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="value"/>
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

          <TextBlock Text="Value:"/>
          <ProgressBar
              Value="{Binding Mode=OneWay}"
              Grid.Column="1" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ListBox>
</Window>
```

Here's the output, notice that the `ProgressBar` isn't stretched, why?
If the items are red, it means that each item fills the entire width, then why isn't the `ProgressBar` stretching??
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have only `SharedSizeGroups` the rest space will never be taken, they always behave like `Width="Auto"` (size to content) with the restriction of the largest item. As you only have two columns you do not even need two such groups as the second will already be the same width in every item, right?

How about this instead:

```
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="name" Width="Auto"/>
    <ColumnDefinition /> <!-- Implicit: Width="*" -->
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Comment: @Shimmy: Glad to hav helped :)

Comment: BTW [`F1`](http://stackoverflow.com/users/546730/h-b) is your enemy, it's only good for distraction, your friend is Google and SO...

Comment: @Shimmy: If you use VS 2010 it is your friend, you get directly to the doc of the thing your cursor is on, be it a class, property, method or whatever.  BTW, you are coding at weird times :P

Comment: @B.H. I did like the <kbd/> tag tho. If it's weird times, what are you doing now?? But it's not weird times it's 03:46 AM, perfect time for coding, THE time for coding!

Comment: @Shimmy: Well i for one am just about to go to bed, but i agree, it's a good time for coding but i wonder how many would share that view.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4678/discussion-between-shimmy-and-h-b)